# Finding Largest Number in Array of Structs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a table that contains an organization name, `org_name`, and an array of structs called `types` that contains structs with properties `name` and `count`. I am attempting to use bigquery to figure out the "dominant" `type` by finding the type with the highest `count` and appending that types `name` to the organizations row. My code to get the organization name and the array of structs is as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetNamesAndCounts(elements ARRAY<STRING>) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT elem AS name, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM UNNEST(elements) AS elem
    GROUP BY elem
    ORDER BY count
  )
);

select org_name, GetNamesAndCounts(types_of_professionals) as types from table
```

This is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAfkV.png) of the results from that query. For context, I would like there to be another column `dominant type` that displays the name of the `type` with the highest `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you order your structs ascending by column `count`, so the last element is what you want (if there is no other `name` with same `count`).
So you can just `GetNamesAndCounts(types_of_professionals)[ordinal(array_length(GetNamesAndCounts(types_of_professionals)))]`

or here is full script

```
select
    org_name,

    array(
        select as struct
            elem as name,
            count(*) as count
        from
            unnest(elements) as elem
        group by
            elem
        order by
            count
    ) as types,

    (   select
            elem
        from
            unnest(elements) as elem
        group by
            elem
        order by
            count(*) desc
        limit
            1
    ) as dominant_type,

    array(
        select
            elem
        from
            (   select
                    elem,
                    count(*) as count,
                    rank() over(partition by
                                    elem
                                order by
                                    count(*) desc) as rank
                from
                    unnest(elements) as elem
                group by
                    elem
            )
        where
            rank = 1
    ) as all_dominant_types
from
    table
```

Comment: [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) easy, no need to resort to threats, just explain me my mistake, that's enough

Comment: Just added calculation of "all dominant types" if there are more than 1

Comment: Super helpful! I created another UDF to maintain the same workflow as before but that worked perfectly. For some reason I forgot I was already ordering by count so it could simply be taken from the top! Thank you so much!